# _doPostBack not definted in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

here is my ASP web Control

```
 <a id="geoLocation" class="geolocate box-outline active full">
            <div>
            <div class="icon"></div>
                <div class="header">
                 Locate Me Now
                    <asp:Label id="latitude" runat="server" ClientIdMode="Static"></asp:Label><br />

                    <asp:Label id="longitude" runat="server" ClientIdMode="Static"></asp:Label>
                    <div style="display:none">
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" ClientIdMode="Static" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </a>
```

I am trying to do a Postback to be able to access the values of "longitude" and "latitude", in the code behind which I intend to make hidden.

this is the postback in Javascipt that I am using ... what am I doing wrong?

```
 function showPosition(position) {
        //  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
        // "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
          document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
          document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
          _doPostBack('#geoLocation', '');


}
```

Comment: `__doPostBack` has two underscores, not one.

Comment: still not defined ... hmmm

Comment: I guess you need ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference

Comment: i tried the ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference in my Page_load method, but ClientScriptManager was not defined either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
_doPostBack('#geoLocation', '');  -->   __doPostBack('#geoLocation', '');
```

You need two underscores at the beginning of the doPostBack method.

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure you have two underscores at the beginning of `__doPostBack`.

Second, the `__doPostBack` function is only available if at least one control on the page calls `Page.RegisterPostBackScript()`. Unfortunately, this method is internal to System.Web.

As a workaround, your control can override `Render` and call [`GetPostBackEventReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackeventreference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will call `Page.RegisterPostBackScript()` for you and return a bit of JavaScript that can be ignored:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(new PostBackOptions(this));
    base.Render(writer);
}
```

Third (in answer to a question you *haven't* asked yet), setting the `innerHTML` property of a Label control will not make the value available to the server on postback. You should instead use a HiddenField control and set its `value` property in JavaScript.

Comment: so just so I am clear, the this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostbackEventReference(new PostbackOptions(this), false) should be placed in my Page_load method of my Codebehind?

Comment: `Page_Load` should work. Personally, though, I prefer to do things as late in the page life cycle as possible, so if *I* were writing the code, I would override `Render` and call it there (before calling `base.Render(writer);`.

Comment: definitely not in Page Load

Comment: well... this code works, but it keep doing the post back until i canceled. i put it in Page_load and in the override of OnRender ... both times it continually kept refreshing the page.

Comment: All GetPostbackEventReference does is declare a `__doPostBack` method; it doesn't call that method. Some other script on your page is probably causing `showPosition` (and thus `__doPostBack`) to be called as soon as the page loads. Hopefully this wasn't intentional. In your JavaScript, add a `debugger;` statement before the call to `__doPostBack` and then look at the call stack in your browser's debugger to see what's calling `showPosition` when the page loads, and change your code so that doesn't happen.

Comment: well ... I tried the Render override method, that did not work.

Comment: If you mean that the page continually refreshes, see my previous comment.

Comment: Do you get "__doPostBack is not defined" again? If you don't get any JavaScript error, can you use your browser's debugger and step into the __doPostBack call?

Comment: no, I took the __doPostBack out of the .js should I have left it in

Comment: If you don't call __doPostBack, the page won't post back.

Comment: How did you fix the problem with the page continually refreshing?

Comment: but, now you are right about not getting my label values ... so, do I need to do a <input type="hidden" etc.

Comment: it was because their was a javascript that is executed everytime the page loads ... so I moved the __doPostBack to a click handler

Comment: You can use `<input type="hidden" name="..." />` or `<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="..." />`, whichever you prefer.